# Single sign on implementation in java using SAML for an enterprise project

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have been assigned to develop a Single Sign On module for an enterprise application in java web app. I am newbie to all these stuff and don't know where to begin.
I have gone through lots of documents on SAML and Single Sign on and got good insight of these but still I am unable to figure out where to begin. 
If anybody can help me with that, I'll appreciate that.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

In a common case like SSO with SAML I would recommend using a SAML product and not do the coding yourself. [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/) is a free and open source solution for SAML.

If you need to build it yourself I would recommend using [Spring SAML module](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) or the [OpenSAML library](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home), but these may give you more work. If you end up using OpenSAML I have a book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), introducing the SAML and the OpenSAML library.

I also have a [blogg with many examples](http://blog.samlsecurity.com/).